# Visual Basic 2013 show sql select in a textbox when a button is pressed

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

In my project, I have a disabled textbox, which i would like to return me a value from a database when i click on a button, the problem is that I don't really know the code in order to do this. I've tried some tutorials here, but no one explains how to return a value when a button is pressed. 
My code is pretty much this:

```
SELECT calorias_refeicao FROM refeicoes
```

Can someone please help me do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is disabled, so the user can't insert any value in it, but it can show data that is in a database.

Comment: sorry now I only know disabled Textbox can programmatically change its content.....so actually your question is how to display sql select result on textbox after you click a button?

Comment: Thanks, but what I really want is that the textbox returns the value from the select I have above when I click a  button.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want!

Comment: For setting text in a `TextBox`, it's something like this: `yourTextBoxName.Text = "THE TEXT"`

Answer (score 0):

C# or VB? If in C# I can provide [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

Moreover, Stackoverflow users aren't going to help you build all code, try coding yourself, and if you are stuck,You can always come back to us without hestitating

Poom

Comment: That tag on the OP's question suggests the OP is using `C#`

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure according to the title

Comment: Thank you, but I need VB code.
I know the users won't build any code for me, however, my real problem is that I have no ideia what the code should be, so i don't really have no code, I just need a light here, just someone else code, I'll adapt later to my project.

Comment: @bublyification I have changed it for you this time, but in future please ensure your tagging is correct, i.e. the correct language that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I find something may help you, if after you try can't help then I will delete this....
[need to get value from sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856686/need-to-get-value-from-sql-query)

you need `ExecuteReader` to help you return the result, then you assign the returned result to a variable then assign it to `TextBox1.Text`?

```vb
  Dim dbName As String
  Using connObj As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("<connectionString>")
     Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT calorias_refeicao FROM refeicoes", connObj)
        connObj.Open()
        Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj.ExecuteReader
           'This will loop through all returned records 
           While readerObj.Read
              dbName = readerObj("name").ToString
              TextBox1.Text = dbName
              'handle returned value before next loop here
           End While
        End Using
        connObj.Close()
     End Using
  End Using
```